# Proper scaling scale - cv::resize, cv::warpAffine, cv::warpPerspective

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

I always had this question, which you can apply either to `cv::resize`, `cv::warpAffine` or `cv::warpPerspective`.

I have an image e.g. 500 x 500 (in C++). I wanna rescale to an image e.g. 1000 x 1000. If I use e.g. OpenCV, it would be something like:

```
const auto fx = scale;
const auto fy = scale;
cv::resize(inputImage, outputImage, cv::Size(), fx, fy)
```

Now, the point is, what is the real value of scale? 2 or 999/499?

Explanation, I want the last pixel on inputImage to go the the last pixel in outputImage, right? That mean pixel 499 to go to 999 (as C++ is 0-based), right? So then, the scale should be 999/499 = 2.002004008, or should just be 2?

I had this question for months and I still could not figure out the solution, my tests just work with basically the same accuracy either way, but I'd like to know the ideal way though.

Comment: It all depends on the math used internally by the scaling algorithm, but I'd expect them to make it 2x. Each pixel from the input will spread out to cover more than one pixel in the output, so input 499 *won't* line up exactly with 999 on the output.

Comment: See http://alvyray.com/Memos/CG/Microsoft/6_pixel.pdf

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks! That PDF and your answer explain it quite well! I cannot choose a comment as correct answer, otherwise I would.